# How to make code which unlock activity by checking IMEI?

Tags: java, android

I know phones IMEI can be get by

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

I've found a time-bomb code for trial app, which give me a new idea. That code was-

```
protected void onResume()
{   
    super.onResume();

    Calendar expirationDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    expirationDate.set(2009, 7, 3);  //hardcoded expiration date
    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();  //Calendar with current time/date
    if (t.compareTo(expirationDate) == 1)
       finish();
}
```

Now i want to make a code which will check IMEI. If IMEI is 123456789123456, application will be unlocked, otherwise it will stop the activity. how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
long imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
if(imei==12345678912345)
         {
            //move to next activity
        }
else
{
         finish();
}
```

Comment: what you tried so far. please debug your code and then you find out which place you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
 long imei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

 if(imei==12345678912345)

     {
       Toast.maketext(getapplicationcontext(),"Your device is unlocked",Toast.lengthlong)).show();

    }
else
{
     finish();
}
```